# How can i make a Program coded on Windows in C# with mono, able to work on linux?

Tags: c#, linux, twitter, mono

How can i make a Program coded on Windows in C# with mono, able to work on linux ?

If i start my Program on linux, i get this: http://pastebin.com/YdnAk7nD.
Maybe its a problem with my code ?:

```
using System;
using Tweetinvi;
using System.Threading;

namespace TwitterBot
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Bot started");

            TwitterCredentials.SetCredentials("*****");

            var loggedUser = User.GetLoggedUser();
            var settings = loggedUser.GetAccountSettings();

            int i = 1;
            int fails = 0;
            while (true) {
                var user = User.GetUserFromId (i);
                i++;

                if (user != null) {
                    loggedUser.FollowUser (user);
                    Console.WriteLine ("Now following: " + user.Name);
                } else {
                    Console.WriteLine("Can not follow user with id: " + i);
                    fails++;
                }

                if (fails >= 100) {
                    fails = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine ("Sleep for 5 minutes");
                    Thread.Sleep (1000 * 60 * 5);
                    Console.WriteLine ("Woken up after 5 minutes");

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweetinvi uses AutoFac 3.*.

[AutoFac (portable library) does not work on mono](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/417)

You could try to get source code for Tweetinvi and compile it against AutoFact for .NET 4 (not portable version) and use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Tweetinvi should work with Mono after the version 4.5. Could you please check the version of Mono you've installed?

Comment: On my Linux i have: Mono JIT compiler version 4.0.2 (Stable 4.0.2.5/c99aa0c Wed Jun 24 10:04:37 UTC 2015)